# Swift 2 How do I implement proxy host and port that requires authorization?

Tags: proxy, swift2, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

This is the code I'm using to send a request using a proxy host and port.  I know the implementation is correct because I'm getting a 407 status code (proxy authentication required).  I don't know why the username/password to the proxy server aren't working.  The credentials are correct and the proxies are active.

```
class Request: NSOperation, NSURLSessionDelegate {
    private var URL:NSURL = NSURL()
    private var method: String
    private var params: String
    private var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    private var cookies: [NSHTTPCookie] = [NSHTTPCookie]()
    private var httpResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse?
    private var contentsOfURL: String?
    private var statusCode: Int?
    var isConnecting = false

    var shouldUseProxy = false
    var proxyHost:CFString!
    var proxyPort:CFNumber!
    var proxyUser:CFString!
    var proxyPW:CFString!

    init(URL: NSURL, method: String, params: String, cookies:[NSHTTPCookie]) {
        self.URL = URL
        self.params = params
        self.method = method
        self.cookies = cookies
    }

    override func main() -> () {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: self.URL)
        request.HTTPMethod = self.method
        if method == "POST" {
            request.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        }
        if self.shouldUseProxy {
            let proxyEnable = NSNumber(int: 1) as NSNumber
            let proxyDict: [NSObject:AnyObject] = [
                kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable: proxyEnable,
                kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost: self.proxyHost,
                kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort: self.proxyPort,
                kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost: self.proxyHost,
                kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort: self.proxyPort,
                kCFProxyTypeKey: kCFProxyTypeHTTPS,
                kCFProxyUsernameKey: self.proxyUser,
                kCFProxyPasswordKey: self.proxyPW
            ]
            let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
            config.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict
            self.session = NSURLSession.init(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue())
        }

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                    let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
                    print("statusCode \(statusCode)")
                }
            self.isConnecting = false
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you sniff the network connection (e.g. using Charles) to check what's sent over the wire? Does it work using HTTP instead of HTTPS? HTTP would be easier for debugging.

Comment: I read a little bit about Charles while doing my research. Is that a third-party application like wire shark? I know that in a browser if I use Http, it does work but it redirects to HTTPS.  Am I to assume that there is no way to enter proxy server settings as you can do on the iPhones ui? I'm saying this because I've searched EVERYWHERE and the only thing I could find is what I have above.

Comment: It's like WireShark indeed. But it also can sniff HTTPS by adding a spoofing CA on the phone. However, it uses a proxy for its operation so that might interfere with the proxy you wanna debug. I'd try to setup a proxy with HTTP only which makes it easier to sniff the connection as it's plaintext.

Comment: You might try using a non-ephemeral session.  This could be a bug caused by the way ephemeral sessions try to store credentials in memory.  If using a non-ephemeral session works, you can mimic an ephemeral session by writing appropriate session delegate methods, using your own memory-only cache, etc. and then store and handle credential storage yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Add additional headers to your config.

```
 func main() -> () {
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: self.URL)
request.HTTPMethod = self.method
if method == "POST" {
    request.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
if self.shouldUseProxy {
    let proxyEnable = NSNumber(int: 1) as NSNumber
    let proxyDict: [NSObject:AnyObject] = [
        kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable: proxyEnable,
        kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost: self.proxyHost,
        kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort: self.proxyPort,
        kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost: self.proxyHost,
        kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort: self.proxyPort,
        kCFProxyTypeKey: kCFProxyTypeHTTPS,
        kCFProxyUsernameKey: self.proxyUser,
        kCFProxyPasswordKey: self.proxyPW
    ]
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
    let config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Proxy-Authorization":  Request.authorizationHeader(user: self.proxyUser, password: self.proxyPW) ]
    config.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyDict
    self.session = NSURLSession.init(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue())
}

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (data, response, error) in
    if error == nil {
        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
        print("statusCode \(statusCode)")
    }
    self.isConnecting = false
}
task.resume()
}
}
```